# SSR index.html compilation

Tags: vue.js, go

I am using Go + VueJS stack, but met a problem with SSR.

I precompile index.html with GO in order to create meta tags (using html/template)

```
{{ range index . "metaTags" }}
  <meta {{.Key |safe }}='{{ .Name }}' {{ .Type |safe }}='{{ .Content }}' data-vue-router-controlled />
  {{ end }}
```

But when I compile with VueJS index.html is variables are set to lower case, so Go can't set variables. Ex. Key is changed to key.

What is the solution to it?

Answer (score 0):

Workaround to it is to pass html generation to function, so html file is replaced with

```
{{ range $el := index . "metaTags" }}
  {{$el|meta}}
  {{ end }}
```

and we register a function to create HTML

```
template.FuncMap{
            "meta": func(s api.Tag) template.HTML {
                return template.HTML("<meta " + s.Key + "=\"" + s.Name + "\"  " + s.Type + "=\"" + s.Content + "\" data-vue-router-controlled />")
            },
        }
```

Struct

```
type Tag struct {
    Key     string `json:"key"`
    Name    string `json:"name"`
    Type    string `json:"type"`
    Content string `json:"content"`
}
```